# jQuery script doesn't seem to work with form displayed with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

I have small application, i set couple of settings first and based on this i display **form** with XMLHttpRequest. My problem is that one of the jQuery script seem not to work with the **form** (script is triggered by pressing the button). If i have exactly the same form displayed standart way, all scripts work properly. There is no errors showing in console.  I'm very stuck. I do use similar technique on many other projets and just can't find what is wrong.

Some Simplified Code:

```
<div id="vans-form-button">
        <input type="button" data-id='1' name='vans-book-btn' id='vans-book-btn' value="NEXT STEP"/>
</div>

<div id="vans-booking-form"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#vans-book-btn").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var elem = $(this), vanid = elem.attr('data-id'); 

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("vans-booking-form").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };        
        console.log("manid:" + id);
        console.log("vanid:" + vanid);
        xmlhttp.open("GET","testform.php?vansize="+vanid+"&manpower="+id,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    });

});
```

So now I have form displayed and some jquery validation scripts work with no problem. It looks to me like JQuery doesn't find a submit button.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name='submit-vans-quote' id="submit-vans-quote" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit-vans-quote").click(function (event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 alert("button was clicked");
....
....
....
    });
});
```

jQuery and all other scripts are placed right at the end of the page. But I also tried with placeing the scripts on top of the page.

Hope I expleain myself properly.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this? maybe that will be helpful to find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had to change:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit-vans-quote").click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert("button was clicked");
   ....
   ....
 });
```

});

to:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit-vans-quote', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("button was clicked");
    ....
    ....
});
```

and that did the trick!